# HTML parser find tag info

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have a project where uses `HTMLParser()`. I never worked with this parser, so I read the documentation and found two useful methods I can override to extract information from the site: `handle_starttag` and `handle_data`. But I don't understand how to find needed tags info and pass the to `handle_data` to print info.

I need to get the price from all span tags on the page

```
<span itemprop="price" content="590">590 dollars</span>
```

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1):

If every `<span>` price tag has the `itemprop` attribute of `"price"` and the dollar amount is in the `content` attribute, then you can do it all in `hanlde_starttag` like this:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrsDict = dict(attrs)
        if tag == 'span' and attrsDict['itemprop'] == 'price':
            price = attrsDict['content']
            print(price)
            # do something else with `price` here


# Example test cases
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed("""
<span itemprop="price" content="590">590 dollars</span>
<span itemprop="price" content="430">430 dollars</span>
<span itemprop="price" content="684">684 dollars</span>
            """)
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will initialize custom `HTMLParser` and get the text between the `<span>` tags (using `handle_data`):

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self._price_tag = None
        self.prices = []


    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "span" and ('itemprop', 'price') in attrs:
            self._price_tag = tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == self._price_tag:
            self._price_tag = None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self._price_tag:
            self.prices.append(data)



parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(r"""\
<html>
    <span itemprop="price" content="570">570 dollars</span>
    <span itemprop="price" content="590">590 dollars</span>
</html>
"""
)

print(parser.prices)
```

Prints:

```
['570 dollars', '590 dollars']
```